# How to solve an AWS Lamba function deployment problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda

.. aaaand me again :)
This time with a very interesting problem.

Again AWS Lambda function, node.js 12, Javascript, Ubuntu 18.04 for local development, aws cli/aws sam/Docker/IntelliJ, everything is working perfectly in local and is time to deploy.

So I did set up an AWS account for tests, created and assigned an access key/secret and finally did try to deploy.

Almost at the end an error pop up aborting the deployment.

I'm showing the SAM cli version from a terminal, but the same happens with IntelliJ.
(of course I mask/change some names)

From a terminal I'm going where I have my local sandbox with the project and then :

```
$ sam deploy --guided

Configuring SAM deploy
======================

        Looking for config file [samconfig.toml] :  Not found

        Setting default arguments for 'sam deploy'
        =========================================
        Stack Name [sam-app]: MyActualProjectName
        AWS Region [us-east-1]: us-east-2
        #Shows you resources changes to be deployed and require a 'Y' to initiate deploy
        Confirm changes before deploy [y/N]: y
        #SAM needs permission to be able to create roles to connect to the resources in your template
        Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation [Y/n]: y
        Save arguments to configuration file [Y/n]: y
        SAM configuration file [samconfig.toml]: y
        SAM configuration environment [default]: 

        Looking for resources needed for deployment: Not found.
        Creating the required resources...
        Successfully created!

                Managed S3 bucket: aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-7qo1hy7mdu9z
                A different default S3 bucket can be set in samconfig.toml

        Saved arguments to config file
        Running 'sam deploy' for future deployments will use the parameters saved above.
        The above parameters can be changed by modifying samconfig.toml
        Learn more about samconfig.toml syntax at 
        https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html
Error: Unable to upload artifact MyFunctionName referenced by CodeUri parameter of MyFunctionName resource.
ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
$
```

I spent quite some time looking around for this problem but I found only some old threads.

In theory this problems was solved in 2018 ... but probably some npm libraries I had to use contains something old ... how in the world I fix this stuff ?

In one thread I found a kind of workaround.

In the file buildspec.yml somebody suggested to add AFTER the npm install :

ls $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
find $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/node_modules -mtime +10950 -exec touch {} ;

Basically  the idea is to touch all the files installed after the npm install but still the error happens.

This my buildspec.yml file after the modification :

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # Install all dependencies (including dependencies for running tests)
      - npm install
      - ls $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - find $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/node_modules -mtime +10950 -exec touch {} ;
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # Discover and run unit tests in the '__tests__' directory
      - npm run test
      # Remove all unit tests to reduce the size of the package that will be ultimately uploaded to Lambda
      - rm -rf ./__tests__
      # Remove all dependencies not needed for the Lambda deployment package (the packages from devDependencies in package.json)
      - npm prune --production
  build:
    commands:
      # Use AWS SAM to package the application by using AWS CloudFormation
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template-export.yml
```

I will continue to search but again I wonder if somebody here had this kind of problem and thus some suggestions/methodology about how to solve it.

Many many thanks !

Steve

Comment: Did you verify that the `touch` command actually updated all 30+ year-old files? It seems like it didn't. Or try the package.json workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2639#issuecomment-308038258) and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: I did verify the syntax and actually was missing the correct command ending  to close the -exec command.
Now it is : find $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/node_modules -mtime +10950 -exec touch {} ';' but still is not working.
I wonder if maybe I don't have the $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR set properly since I don't even see in the log the ls output ...
Thanks

Comment: Why not just go to the root folder of your project and use `find . -mtime +10950` to find all old files? Re-run with the (correct) touch option or just do it manually if there aren't too many files. There's no legitimate reason to have files dated 2000 or earlier that I can think of.

Comment: I usually prefer to target specifically an area rather than blank everything but yeah, if I can not find faster where the build area is (I suspect the build process creates a temporary directory somewhere) I might try to touch everything.
Of course this assuming the temporary building directory is created IN the local project space.
Thanks

Comment: From IntelliJ I was able to deploy just telling to build in a docker rather than from the system. 
I wonder if the problem is somehow related specifically to Ubuntu.
I will try later to set up the dev environment on a Mac rather than Linux and see if I still have the same issue ... very annoying chasing ghosts :)